# Why does only one of these formulas work in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

B10 = 'High"

```
=SORT(CONCATENATE(B10,"!B3:", B10, "!AK42"), High!AL3:High!AL42, TRUE)
```

That returns the error `SORT has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 1. column count: 1. Actual row count: 40, column count: 1.`

However,

```
=SORT(High!B3:High!AK42, High!AL3:High!AL42, TRUE)
```

Works without any problems. Is there an easier way to achieve what I'm doing, or can I make this work with some changes? I'm essentially trying to get a sorted array (B3:AK42 sorted by AL3:AL42) from a sheet (High) specified in a cell (B10).

Comment: You probably need to use `INDIRECT`  in the first one.

Comment: Same error unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Your first parameter to the `Sort` function needs to be a range. The result of `Concatenate` is a string, so you need to do something to convert it. `Indirect` will do the trick, but `Indirect` converts a single cell reference, not a range. So, you need to use one `Indirect` for the first end of the range, and another `Indirect` for the other end.

```
=SORT(Indirect(B10&"!B3"):Indirect(B10&"!AK42"), High!AL3:High!AL42, TRUE)
```

(I used `&` notation instead of the `Concatenate` function. I find it easier to read.)

Answer (score -1):

- try it like this:

  ```
  =SORT(INDIRECT(B10 & "!B3:AK42"), High!AL3:AL42, 1)
  ```

  ```
  =SORT(INDIRECT(B10 & "!B3:AK42"), INDIRECT(B10 & "!AL3:AL42"), 1)
  ```